# Automatically Upscale all uploaded images in Wordpress and Keeping Aspect Ratio

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, resize, code-snippets

I Had some trouble recently trying to automatically upscale (resize) all small uploaded images to my wordpress website, i tried many plugins but i found only the opposite (Bigger to small for compression).
So after a moment,
i did find a solution for this case, and i would like to share the solution with you guys.

- Install Code Snippets Plugin.
- Add this code bellow

```
// Function to upscale uploaded images
function upscale_uploaded_images($metadata) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    // Check if the uploaded file is an image
    if (isset($metadata['width']) || $metadata['width'] < 600) {
        $file_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $metadata['file'];
   // Here you can change the width you want to upscale to recommanded is 1280
        $new_width = 1280;

        // Open the image
        $image = wp_get_image_editor($file_path);

        if (!is_wp_error($image)) {
            $aspc = $metadata['width'] / $metadata['height'];
            // Calculate the new height while maintaining the aspect ratio
            $metadata['width'] = $new_width;
            $metadata['height'] = intval($new_width/$aspc);

            // Resize the image
            $image->resize($new_width,  $metadata['height'], true); 
            $image->save($file_path);

            // Update the image metadata
            wp_update_attachment_metadata($metadata['attachment_id'], $metadata);
        }
    }

    return $metadata;
} 
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'upscale_uploaded_images');

// Enable the intermediate image sizes  
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', function ($sizes) {
    $sizes[] = 'medium_large';
    return $sizes;
});
```